# Compounding array only if a certain key exists in array element

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

In laravel, I have a working code block where I loop an array and within it I call an email list. However, there are certain elements in the array that have a specific email that I want to add to it. So I always want the existing email config list to be used no matter what, but if the array element of the person has an email key I want to add that to the emails array, if that makes sense.

Here is the existing code as it:

```
    $items = array(
        array(
            "employee" => 123,
            "name" => "Tom",
            "email" => "Tom@sitepoint.com"
        ),
        array(
            "employee" => 234,
            "name" => "Sally"
        ),
        array(
            "employee" => 345,
            "name" => "Rob"
        ),
        array(
            "employee" => 456,
            "name" => "Ed"
            "email" => "ed@sitepoint.com"
        ),
        array(
            "employee" => 567,
            "name" => "Barbara"
        )
    );

    foreach($items as $item){

        //if there is an override email in the command
        if($this->option('email') != 'default') {
           
            if(!filter_var($this->option('email'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $this->error('invalid email:'.$this->option('email'));
                return;
            }
        
            $emails = ['to'=>[$this->option('email')],'cc'=>[]];
        
        } else {

            //This line works as is but I want a condition so that if the array element has and "email" key, I add that value as well
            $emails = config('emails.printouts.employeePrintOuts');

            //here I would need to add the array value (if email is set in that element)

        }


        ...

    }
```

The part in question is only in the 'else' block. How can I properly do this so that only certain array elements will have an email key and if they do I add it to the emails array that is always using the config list?

Comment: [`array_key_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)?

Comment: So if I use that, I could add that email into the array, but then if run the existing line for the config will it add to the array or just replace it?

Comment: You can use that to check if a key exists in an array, you'll have to write the logic yourself

Comment: If you want to not overwrite, but just add email, then you also can check email existing in array with `in_array()` function. Try this:
`  
if (array_key_exist('email',$item)){
    if (!in_array($item['email],$emails['to'])){
        $emails['to'][] = $item['email'];
    }
}  
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you can use `array_key_exist()` function to check that `$items` contain `email` key.

Also to fullfil `$emails['to']` subarray only in case that it doesn't contain current `$items['email']` you may use `in_array()` function.

Solution:

```php
if ( array_key_exist('email', $item) && !in_array($item['email'], $emails['to']) )
{
    //TODO validate $item['email'] here
    $emails['to'][] = $item['email'];
}

//Result $emails array will be looks like this:
[
 'to' => [ "Tom@sitepoint.com", "ed@sitepoint.com" ],
 'cc' => []
]
```